# Выполнить функцию, по завершении 3-х потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такой вопрос:

Есть три потока (`Thread`) и есть функция `А`, которая должна выполниться только после того, как все три потока отработали. В принципе, можно проверять в каждом потоке, по завершении, выполнились ли остальные, и тогда запускать функцию `А` или нет. Мне такой вариант кажется громоздким. Как можно еще запустить функцию `А` только после того, как все три потока отработали?

Comment: Вариант с Join правильный, добавлю лишь, что вместо устаревших потоков надо использовать `async` и `Task`'и, так что ваш код должен выглядеть как `await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3); A();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `Thread.Join` останавливает выполнение вызывающего потока, пока вызванный поток не прекратит работу. Например, так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new Thread(DoSomething1);
        var t2 = new Thread(DoSomething2);
        var t3 = new Thread(DoSomething3);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        t3.Join();

        A();
    }

    private static void DoSomething1()
    {
        // do something 1
    }

    private static void DoSomething2()
    {
        // do something 2
    }

    private static void DoSomething3()
    {
        // do something 3
    }

    private static void A()
    {
        // do A;
    }
}
```